# How can BLE devices be connected using the socket API of Windows7? It basically works but I'm having issues

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth-lowenergy, winsock

I'm working on a C++ application that communicates with my custom (nRF52840-based) hardware through BLE. The application should work on Windows, and it would be good to support Windows 7 too.

Despite the fact that there is no official BLE support for Win7, BLE seems to be working to some extent. My iPhone, BLE mouse are working properly. However I'm not able to connect to any BLE devices from my code.

Tried this example:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/winsock/bluetooth/bthcxn.cpp

The application successfully discovers all nearby BLE devices. It attempts to connect to the selected device, but connect() always returns with error and WSAGetLastError() returns 10035 (WSAEWOULDBLOCK). Repeated connect() calls return with this same error all the time.
The connection seems to be established on the device side, but not on the Windows side. All subsequent send() calls result in 10057 (WSAENOTCONN).
Pairing the device or not does not seem to have any effect.

The behavior is the same on Windows 10 too. Connecting to other devices (tried with an iPhone and with another notebook) failed in the same way.

How do I make it working? Did anyone succeeded in implementing BLE communication using sockets?

Comment: Windows 7 (and Windows Vista and Window s8) does not support BLE with Microsoft stack. You have to use third party Bluetooth drivers for that. BlueSoleil is one way to get BLE on Win 7. BLE support by Microosft Bluetooth drivers started from Windows 8.1

Comment: Add.: WinSOck Bluetooth API supports only Classic Bluetooth RFCOMM connection. On any Windows platform. WIn 8.1 (and above) hs different API for BLE communication. In fact there are 2: Legacy and WinRT (UWP).

Comment: As mentioned in the question, BLE is working on my computer. I'm using it every day. I believe, the Intel stack is used for the integrated Intel BLE module.

Comment: Pairing works, discovering my device works, even connect() works to some extent - connection is considered established on the device side!
Okay, let's assume that this API is broken. Could someone point me to the API that I could use on Win7? Is there some universal solution or is it always stack dependent?

Comment: It probably works, but there is no API for your Intel stack. Connect and discovering works because your device is "mixed" one: it appears as BLE and as Classic. Windows API on Win 7 suppoorts only classic Bluetooth. It does not support BLE. WinSock (if you open its documentation) supports only RFCOMM.

Comment: My device is BLE only. The HW is physically incapable of the modulation required for classic (nRF52840) and the SW does not support that either.

The notebook is working fine with other BLE only devices. Tested with my iPhone SE, which is BLE onl, and also with a Xiaomi Mi Mouse. The mouse employs an nRF5182, which is also BLE only, even simpler than my own HW.

I understand that the RFCOMM API might be insufficient to implement communication through BLE.

Comment: Is it possible to implement custom BLE communication on Win7, or is the case that only "standard equipment" like phones, mice can work with the built-in drivers?

Comment: Ok, let it be so. I have no time to explain how Bluetooth works so let it be so. Any way, yes there is a way to use BLE on Win 7: use third party Bluetooth stack or develop your own.

Comment: And by the way: all your devices is not "BLE only". They are common Bluetooth devices. Bluetooth 4 (and Bluetooth 5) does not mean "BLE only". It just means that they support Bluetooth 4 (and above) specification. And nothing more. nrf52840 is dual mode device in fact (read its specification).

Comment: nRF52840 can do BLE, Ant, and proprietary radio. It's not dual mode. It cannot do BT 2.1. (I read the specs of course)
iPhone 4 was the last that supported BT 2.1. From the 4s only BLE is supported and iPhones can no more talk to BT classic devices.
My Lenovo T460 has dual mode BT as it can talk to both 2.1 devices (e.g. BlueGiga WT11/WT12 modules) and to iPhone / nRF51/52 BLE modules.
Mouse, WiFi hotspot connections work.

Comment: You are mixing together very different things. iPhone 4s (and any other cell) works perfectly with classic Bluetooth devices (tell me how do you connect hands free module to your cell? Do you think it works over BLE?) I do recomend to read some Bluetooth specifications first to understand differences between BLE/Classic and Bluetooth specification (version) number.

Comment: This can be the case. What I see is that current iPhones can't see purely classic modules (like the WT11/WT12), they can see only BLE modules like the nRF51/52 devices.
But this might be a profile issue, Apple might have disabled features after iPhone 4.

What I see now that modules that are BLE only (100%) are working with my notebook, but I can't access them from own software. This is what I want to sort out...

Comment: So interesting experiments would be implementing a handsfree with the WT11/WT12 modules and check whether the iPhones see it, and implementing a HID device with nRF51/52 and figure whether they're accessible through some Win7 API...

Comment: Much faster and cheaper way - read the manual (specification).

Comment: Sure, which one? The general conclusion is that it's impossible under win7, however in practice all my BLE devices and custom HW work properly with the "default" driver. Obviously there is no built-in driver for presenters, but Logitech somehow managed to create a driver for theirs.
I'm looking into creating such a driver for my HW and need information how to start.

Comment: Start from Bluetooth Core specification. Next, if you would like to develop own driver, you have to run into WDK. Those are good starting points.

Comment: If you do not want to learn all the thing here is the very short description: You iPhone 4s is standard Bluetooth 4.0 device with BLE support. Even if it is marked as Bluetooth 4.0 compatible it does NOT mean that is supports BLE (of course, iPhone 4s does). You iPhone has standard Bluetooth (classic) profiles: SPP, DUN, HFP, A2DP - all of them are classic, not BLE. And of course your iPhone can be discovered and CAN discover as classic Bluetooth device.

Comment: Now your HID device. Even if your HID device supports BLE I do not think it does not support classic HID profile. Because there are not too many devices that can be used with HID over BLE profile. So you HID device also supports classic HID profile.

Comment: Now you custom HW. I have no time to learn all the things about your chip but in the first lines of its description I found that it also supports classic Bluetooth. So it can be discovered as classic Bluetooth device without any problem.

Comment: Now back to Win 7. Microsoft Bluetooth drivers on Windows 7 DOES NOT support BLE. But it can discover ALL your devices because all of them support Classic Bluetooth.

Comment: Now ablut BLE and Bluetooth Core specification. Bluetooth Core specification number just describes possible features of the device. If device marked as Bluetooth 4.0 or Bluetooth 5.0 or anyhow else it DOES NOT mean that it is BLE device. It just means that device follows specified Bluetooth Core specification. BLE is OPTIONAL in all of them (may be except BT 5, I did not read it completly yet).

Comment: Thanks! You're thinking in profiles, but note that the LE and classic physical layers are different. They're using the same frequency range, but the channel assignment and the modulation are different. BLE devices, like the nRF51/52 RFSOC's cannot do classic.The HW is physically not capable of that. Classic is much more complicated.

Comment: The situation is that the earlier versions of our devices were using BlueCore 2 and 4 chips from CSR (classic only), and they were never detected by iPhones. Mobile devs claimed that classic would never work with iPhones.
So now I'm looking into BLE. I'm not sure in the iPhone, but I'm 100% sure that my nRF52840-based HW and the Xiaomi Mi Mouse (nRF51822 based) are BLE only and have absolutely no possibility to use classic. All work with win7 with the built-in drivers, all are discoverable with my SW, but connect does not work to any of them.

Comment: The standard says that backward compatibility is supported. In my understanding 4.0 devices might support 2.1 too, but this is optional. Makes sense, a real LE device, which runs on a coin cell for years, cannot implement classic.
Do you have any example, how to connect to BLE on win7? Did not manage to find any working examples. I guess the win10 examples would work, but as of now it is quite important to support win7 too.
The good news is that configuring an 52840 board as a UART-NUS gateway works very well with my device. It might be an acceptable temp solution.

Comment: As I already wrote few time: to get BLE working on Win 7 you must use third party drivers. One of them is BlueSoleil. Its not the best solution but at least it has some documentation and supported by third-party libraries. The othe solution is to use WinUSB based driver. There are 2 (at least I know 2). The first one is HciSocket from BLENO (requires lot of coding to add ATT and GATT support). The other one is BlueKitchen (free for learning and non commercial use as far as I know).

Comment: miMous also supports classic mode. And also may use custom adapter (2.4Ghz does not always mean Bluetooth). nRF51822 is BLE but also can be flashed for classic stack. And any BLE device (except Beacon) can be discovered as classic because of advertisement packet format. That is because to be able to use GATT profile the device must implement L2CAP whci requires classic advertisement. Please redad Bluetooth Core for more details.

Comment: The other possible reason why it works is that your Win 7 already has third party driver installed. You should know that starting from WIn 7 MS updated Bluetooth stack and now any vendo can write Bluetooth driver expantion driver (actually it is filter driver). This third party driver handles BLE requests. But it still appears as Microsoft Bluetooth driver and all MS BT API is available. But ther eis no way to get BLE working with Microsoft Bluetooth drivers even with such extention. Because MS API on Win 7 does not include any code for BLE support (no HCI, no GATT - nothing).

Comment: https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/573/can-the-nrf51822-support-classic-bluetooth
No Nordic device supports BT Classic. As said earlier, it's physically impossible.
I do have a 3rd BLE stack running, that's why BLE devices work with the notebook. It's from Intel. The driver can be downloaded but there is no API specification included. I assumed that some standard API is emulated.

Comment: The MiMouse also supports a proprietary radio protocol with its USB dongle besides BLE. But not Classic. I used BlueSoleil earlier, but I guess I would need a dongle again. It might not support the integrated Intel Bluetooth in notebooks. This filter driver might be the solution for Win7 - I'm looking into it.

Comment: Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth Low Energy can actually be considered as two different technologies only sharing the Bluetooth brand name. The protocols are different all the way down to the physical layer. BT Classic, for example, use radio 79 channels spaced 1 MHz apart, while BLE use only 39 channels spaced 2 MHz apart. Hence, you cannot have a Bluetooth Classic device communicate with a Bluetooth Smart Device. Check out the Bluetooth Core Specification for more details.